# Does active power factor correction help with internal radiated/conducted noise?

Tags: noise, emc, ac-dc, power-factor-correction

I am choosing parts for the supply of a device. The case will be a metal chassis and there will be an AC-DC (12 V) converter module inside mounted on the chassis. The total AC power draw will be less than 75 W. So power factor correction is *not* mandatory. The 12 V rail will be further converted by various other isolated and non-isolated DC-DC converters to various power rails.

As the device will also contain precision analog circuits (DC-50 kHz), I want to minimize sources of radiated and conducted interference within the device as much as possible.

**Would there be an advantage or disadvantage in choosing an AC-DC-converter that has active PFC?**

I think that the AC side of such a converter would be less noisy but I am unsure about the DC side, because after all there is more switching going on. So the ripple spectrum could contain low frequency intermodulation frequencies if PFC and power switching are at different frequencies.

**More details:**

The comments suggest that there is no general answer. I will add an example of two parts:

- [No PFC Meanwell LRS series](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/LRS-75/LRS-75-SPEC.PDF)
- [Active PFC Meanwell RSP series](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/RSP-75/RSP-75-SPEC.PDF)

Both have identical output ripple specs. However, the LRS output ripple would be at 65 kHz and its harmonics and the lower frequency range of sub 50 kHz would be rather clean. In contrast, the RSP has different frequencies for power PWM and PFC, namely 65 kHz and 80 kHz. Therefore, I would expect to see also intermodulation frequencies, e.g. at 15 kHz, which would make matters worse in the low frequency spectrum and I would need better output filtering.

So is it wise to avoid active PFC (if it is not mandatory) for the sake of the lower output noise in the low frequency range between DC and say 50 kHz?

Comment: Can you link to specific systems you are considering? In general, I would go with the system noise specs and all else being equal I'd go with the higher PFC, because that implies less noise added to the AC. But, if your main concern is output noise, you should look at the output noise specs.

Comment: Generalisms are not going to give you what you want to know,

Comment: @pscheidler I have added more details. I was wondering initially if there would be a general trend on this question. That is why I formulated the question broadly at first.

Comment: I would say disadvantage. Mo’ switching - mo’ EMI.